# Substituir espaço por virgula e pipe intercaladamente

Tags: php

Tenho uma determinada string abaixo, como podem ver, são coordenadas separadas  apenas por um espaço. Vejam:

> -23.5209 -46.46466 -23.52008 -46.465952 -23.519253 -46.467239 -23.518808 -46.466901 -23.518738 -46.466848 -23.518411 -46.466597 -23.518349 -46.46658 -23.51834 -46.46657 -23.517974 -46.466157 -23.517879 -46.466052 -23.517859 -46.466074 -23.51733 -46.466632 -23.516765 -46.467217 -23.516693 -46.467292 -23.516206 -46.467802 -23.516169 -46.467841 -23.516179 -46.467859 -23.516229 -46.467909 -23.516329 -46.467981 -23.518096 -46.469056

Basicamente o primeiro item é a latitude, segundo é longitude e assim por diante. Preciso que fique desta forma abaixo, que é a separação entre latitude e longitude por virgula, e entre coordenada por pipe. Veja:

> -23.5209,-46.46466|-23.52008,-46.465952|-23.519253,-46.467239|-23.518808,-46.466901|-23.518738,-46.466848 ...

Qual seria melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode tentar o uso de `preg_replace`, algo como `(-[\d.]+)\s(-[\d.]+)(\s|$)`, resultado:

```
<?php

$x = '-23.5209 -46.46466 -23.52008 -46.465952 -23.519253 -46.467239 -23.518808 -46.466901 -23.518738 -46.466848 -23.518411 -46.466597 -23.518349 -46.46658 -23.51834 -46.46657 -23.517974 -46.466157 -23.517879 -46.466052 -23.517859 -46.466074 -23.51733 -46.466632 -23.516765 -46.467217 -23.516693 -46.467292 -23.516206 -46.467802 -23.516169 -46.467841 -23.516179 -46.467859 -23.516229 -46.467909 -23.516329 -46.467981 -23.518096 -46.469056';

$x = preg_replace('#(-[\d.]+)\s(-[\d.]+)(\s|$)#', '$1,$2|', $x);
$x = rtrim($x, '|'); //Remove o pipe extra no final

echo $x;
```

- O `(-[\d.]+)` procura um numero como `-46.467909`
- O `\s(-[\d.]+)(\s|$)` procuta o que vem após "primeiro" numero, troca o primeiro espaço por virgula e o segundo por pipe `|`, se não houver espaço no final adiciona o pipe (que é removido pelo `rtrim`).

Ele vai "rodar" a `string` toda substituindo, desta maneira se substituir o segundo espaço diretamente não vai ocorrer dele passar novamente no segundo espaço e acidentalmente adicionar uma virgula.

Exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/f5MGiQ)

Comment: Pelo que percebi, a ultima coordenada não se encaixa no regex. Se remover o `\s` do final ai sim funciona. Acha que pode influenciar removendo?! O que o `\s` faz exatamente!?

Comment: @acklay `\s` é um meta caracter de `match espaços`; talvez `\s?` para fazer match opcional?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não entendi se você está me afirmando algo ou se está fazendo uma pergunta. xD

Comment: @acklay vou reescrever. 1) `\s` casa todo e qualquer espaço, como `\d` casa dígitos; 2) `\s?` torna opcional a presença do espaçamento, pode resolver o problema da última coordenada